# How to store binary data in etcd v3 using CLI

Tags: etcd

It's simple to extract etcd data in json(base64) or hex formats with either -w json or --hex flags

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl get /registry/secrets/myns/mykey --print-value-only --hex 
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl get /registry/secrets/myns/mykey -w json
```

But how can one write hex/json extracted data from another etcd instance via cli?
`etcdctl put` doesn't accept any of these parameters and will store passed value as string

Answer (score 3):

etcd can take input from stdin, so the data can be piped in

GET the value in json(base64 encoded):

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl get key -w json | jq .kvs[].value | tr -d \" > value.b64
```

PUT decoded value on the same/other etcd instance

```
base64 -D -i ./value.b64 | ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl put key
```